# How do I uncompress vmlinuz to vmlinux?

Tags: linux, 7-zip, linux-kernel, gzip, compression

I have already tried uncompress, gzip, and all other solutions that come up as google results and these have not worked for me.

> To get just the image search for the GZ signature - `1f 8b 08 00`.
>
> ```
> > od -A d -t x1 vmlinuz | grep '1f 8b 08 00'
> 0024576 24 26 27 00 ae 21 16 00 1f 8b 08 00 7f 2f 6b 45
> ```
>
> so the image begins at `24576+8 => 24584`. Then just copy the image from the point and decompress it -
>
> ```
> > dd if=vmlinuz bs=1 skip=24584 | zcat > vmlinux
> 1450414+0 records in
> 1450414+0 records out
> 1450414 bytes (1.5 MB) copied, 6.78127 s, 214 kB/s
> ```
>
> Got these instructions verbatim from a forum online: http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=415186

This process does not work for me and end up giving errors that states file not found 0024576 and all subsequent numbers.

How do I proceed extracting vmlinux from vmlinuz?

Thank you.

EDITED: This is a reverse engineering question. I have no access to the distro to install any RPM or recompile. I start with nothing but vmlinuz.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: This is actually for a friend who had to do something with it. The question seemed interesting and I pursued it for my academic interest. An alternative to this is to build the kernel :-/

Comment: Well, for academic interest, I don't know if it's easily possible.  I believe a vmlinuz kernel has an executable preamble--it's essentially a self-extracting archive. That's why using straight gunzip didn't work for you.  The quoted method attempts to skip past that preamble. Why it doesn't work, I don't know for sure. Maybe somebody else with similar academic interests can give you a useful answer. :)

Answer (score 37):

[The kernel sources now contain a script for this, `extract-vmlinux`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/scripts/extract-vmlinux). You don't need to roll your own.

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12002789/398670).

Comment: Is this available in Ubuntu 14.04? I seen it in the git repo, what ubuntu package can I find it in? - Thank you :-)

Comment: @LordLoh `apt-file search extract-vmlinux` gives several linux kernel header packages, and `locate extract-vmlinux` leads to a few hits on my local Ubuntu 18.04 machine: `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-33/scripts/extract-vmlinux` although nothing in `PATH` it seems.

Comment: For ARM it fails with "extract-vmlinux: Cannot find vmlinux": https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/352215/how-do-i-extract-vmlinux-from-an-arm-image

Answer (score 34):

Maybe you misunderstood what the author of that post meant.

1. The `vmlinuz` file contains other things besides the gzipped content, so you need to find out where the gzipped content starts. To do that, use:

   ```
   od -A d -t x1 vmlinuz | grep '1f 8b 08 00'
   ```

   What this does is to show you where in that file you can find the gzip header. The output looks like:

   ```
   0024576 24 26 27 00 ae 21 16 00 1f 8b 08 00 7f 2f 6b 45
   ```

   This means that at `0024576` (at least for the author of the post, yours might be somewhere completely different) in the `vmlinuz` file, you will find the binary values "`24 26 27 00 ae 21 16 00 1f 8b 08 00 7f 2f 6b 45`". You're looking for `1f 8b 08 00`, which can be found from character 9 onwards, or, at `0024576 + 8` (start counting from 0) `= 24584`.
2. Now that you know where the gzipped content starts (at position `24584`) you can use `dd` to extract that gzipped content and ungzip it. To do that, use:

   ```
   dd if=vmlinuz bs=1 skip=24584 | zcat > vmlinux
   ```

   The first command will seek to that position and copy everything to stdout. `zcat` then will uncompress everything it gets from stdin and will output the uncompressed string to stdout. Then the `>` will redirect `zcat`'s output to a new file named `vmlinux`.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense now.

However, '1f 8b 08 00' did nor return anything for my kernel after a few seconds of execution. Apparently the code has changed. Any suggestion on how to get the new set of magic numbers?

Comment: @Lord Loh.: Two possibilities: 1) The magic numbers cross line boundaries in `od`'s output. Use [bgrep](https://github.com/tmbinc/bgrep/blob/master/bgrep.c) to search for `1f8b0800`. 2) The kernel is compressed using a different algorithm. Try `fd377a585a00` for *xz* or `425a6839` for *bzip2*.

Comment: @ grawity - Thank you for the reply. I tried that. neither 1f8b0800, fd377a585a00 nor 425a6839 returned any results. So I started chopping down the magic string byte by byte till I got some results, and they were hundreds of matches :-( So I am still without success.

Comment: LZMA is "5d 00 00 80" according to http://minimodding.com/tiki-index.php?page=BinaryDecomposition#Locating_a_LZMA_binary. Still didn't work for me.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, before generating the `vmlinuz` file, most symbols are stripped. So you cannot rebuild a true `vmlinux` from `vmlinuz`, the file will not be as useful for debugging.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into simple problem - looking for correct version of vmlinux for crash. Instead of trying to decompress vmlinuz to vmlinux.

The better solution is: install the RPM: `kernel-debuginfo`, that RPM contains proper vmlinux file.

Pay attention to the rpm name, there are multiple similar (confusing) names. Gotta be: `kernel-debuginfo-$(version).rpm`

Answer (score 2):

Modern kernels are not always (in fact, not generally) gzip compressed. They may use bzip2 or LZMA. A quick web search didn't help me find the magic strings for those compression methods--you might be better off checking several kernel images to find the invariant header that includes the decompression code.

Answer (score 1):

The decompression lines above worked for me and, of course, the kernel was stripped.  Therefore no good information there.

If you need to make changes to your old kernel, like put it in debug, use `uname -r` to get the revision of your kernel and get its source:

```
sudo apt-get source linux-image-\`uname -r\`
```

The source will be in `/usr/src/linux...`  `cd` to the source tree and:

```
make oldconfig
make
```

This will attempt to find the file containing the config for the currently running kernel -- usually

```
/boot/config-\`uname -r\`
```

and use it for this build thus recreating the running kernel.

Build that the way you want it; have access to the unstripped kernel as needed.

The shells above probably won't find the gzip magic number due to spacing.  Yes they are still compressed the same way, though I'm writing a year after the original discussion. Send the output to `less` and search for `1f 8b` or even `1f`.  Check the rest of the bytes manually to determine a match and verify you have the first instance.  Use the offset found remembering it is decimal.

Answer (score 0):

You might not have readelf installed and need the elfutils package installed with the call being eu-readelf instead.